# iphone - Create NSMutableDictionary filled with NSMutableArrays dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have an array of objects. Each object has property "date" and "title".
I want to populate sectioned `UITableView` with those items like:

```
Section 1 - 2012.06.12 (taken from object.date)
  Cell 1.1: Title 1 (taken from object.name)
  Cell 1.2: Title 2
  Cell 1.3: Title 3
  ...
Section 2 - 2012.06.13
  Cell 2.1: Title 1
  Cell 2.2: Title 2
  ..
Section 3 ..
```

I can do that by manually creating *1..n* NSMutableArrays for all `date` combinations and filling them with `object.name` values. But the problem is I do not know how many `date` combinations there are, so it should be done dynamically. Also, the `date` property can repeat in different objects
My object structure is:

```
Object
 -NSDate - date
 -NSString - title
```

**UPD**:

I was thinking if it is possible to create NSDictionary, where the key would be my date and the object would be NSArray, which contains all my items for the key-date. But I do not know how to do that dynamically.

I hope I explained my question clearly enough. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your each object contain 3 titles?Can you show your object structure?

Comment: From where you take the dates?

Comment: I have updated my question. Each object has only one title. Titles in examples are taken from different objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create arrays based on date.You have array of objects, so iterate through this array of objects to get distinct dates, as follows:

```
for(int i =0;i<[objectsArr count];i++)
{
   if(![newDateArr containsObject:[objectsArr objectAtIndex:i].date])
   {
      [newDateArr addObject:[objectsArr objectAtIndex:i].date];
   }
   NSMutableArray *newTitleArray = [newTitleDictionary objectForKey:@"[objectsArr objectAtIndex:i].date"];
   if(newTitleArray != nil)
   {
      [newTitleArray addObject:[objectsArr objectAtIndex:i].title];
   }
   else
   {
      newTitleArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
      [newTitleArray addObject:[objectsArr objectAtIndex:i].title];
   }
   [newTitleDictionary setValue:newTitleArray forKey:@"[objectsArr objectAtIndex:i].date"];
}
```

where newTitleDictionary and newDateArr are declare outside this method.Now you can use both is newTitleDictionary and newDateArr to populate tableview.

Comment: Great idea! I did it in the same way and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to put an object into an array and then use that array to populate a table view?

Just add the date object each time to the NSMutableArray.

```
[myArray addObject:dateObject];
```

Then when it comes to populating the table view..

```
DateObject *newDateObj = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];
```

I hope this helps and I understood your question

**EDIT** To answer now I understand a bit more.

**Step 1**
Check through the existing array of dates and see if there are any that match maybe by iterating through it using a for loop. Search online for how to compare NSDate.

**Step 2** If it **doesn't** match any then insert it into the array as an array with just that date on it's own so the array count will be one. If it **does** match then insert it into the array along with that one making the array count 2 or more.

**Step 3** When it comes to declaring the section amount for the table just return the dateHolderArray count.

**Step 4** When declaring the amount of rows in each section, return the array count for the array thats inside the dateHolderArray.

**Step 5** Display the content when it comes to populating the cells with information. It becomes just a task of getting the dates from the arrays using the section ids and row ids.

This is how I would do it, there are probably many other methods. Any questions just ask

Comment: I can't do like that, because there might be repeating dates

Comment: so you want to check if a date is the same as another in the array and if so maybe add that to a new array so they are grouped under one date?

Comment: check my answer for steps to how I would do what you want